# Fatal error: Wrong parameters for Exception

Tags: php, mercadopago

Estoy teniendo un problema al generar un cobro desde una aplicación interna con el botón de MP.

Anteriormente me tiraba un error en la línea 508, la cual pude "corregir", pero ahora, al ejecutar dicho botón, me tira el error:

> Fatal error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long
>   $code ]]) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cc\sdk-php-master\lib\mercadopago.php on
>   line 576"

private static function build_request($request) {
        if (!extension_loaded ("curl")) {
            throw new MercadoPagoException("cURL extension not found. You need to enable cURL in your php.ini or another configuration you have.");
        }

La verdad que me recorrí todos los sitios, pero con ninguno llego a la solución.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Estaría perfecto que incluyeras el código donde te está marcando el error, así como lo pones dificilmente alguien te ayudará

Comment: private static function build_request($request) {
        if (!extension_loaded ("curl")) {
            throw new MercadoPagoException("cURL extension not found. You need to enable cURL in your php.ini or another configuration you have.");
        }

Comment: Bueno, pon el código en tu post, no en un comentario, editalo.

Comment: Ahi lo agrego! Soy nuevo en esto! gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ahí está tu problema, el cURL no está habilitado en tu PHP. Por lo general el cURL se usa para hacer peticiones de backend a backend.

Como veo que tu problema es XAMPP nos vamos directo a la solución.

1. Tenemos que ir a `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`
   Por lo general está ahí si no, encuentra el archivo php.ini
2. Busca la línea: `extension=php_curl.dll` y asegúrate que no esté comentada.
3. Si continúa sin jalar asegurate que tu carpeta Windows32 tenga estos dos archivos `libeay32.dll ssleay32.dll` si no los tiene bájalos de internet.

Con eso debería bastar.

Comment: Me sigue tirando error en la misma linea, luego de hacer las 2 cosas mencionadas. Puedo copiar el codigo y me indican en que le estoy pifeando por fa?